# Performance of UITableviewcell image background vs CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, performance, uitableview, cashapelayer

Here's my question: It's about best practice for scrolling in UITableview with many rows. I want to add a shape to each cell as the background to one element. Think Facebook messeger bubbles. My first go I created `CAShapeLayer` and created my path and then set that layers frame to my textview frame. This worked.

However another developer suggested performance on a UIImage with resizeable insets was better than using a CAShapelayer.

Which one is better for scrolling? Second I can't find mention anywhere is CAShapeLayers are off screen rendering or onscreen. The shape will be in every cell and it's size is dependent on the size of text.

Comment: Come on reviewers. Don't approve edits that do not add or improve the post. Capitalizing a class name fails to fall into a helpful edit. It is our job as reviewers to reject these. @yunus please make sure edits improve a post. There is a list of edit reasons that are helpful to follow.

Comment: Any time you feel you can make the post better, and are inclined to do so. Editing is encouraged!

Some common reasons to edit are:

to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes
to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it
to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages
to add related resources or hyperlinks

Comment: As per listed reject reason for us editors "This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability." Reviewers should make sure an edit adds value. I am asking the reviewers to read the reject reasons